# Convert powershell script saving outlook attachments to save them from not inbox but inbox subfolder

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a script i scraped from other scripts. It works except i am quite new to powershell and am a sys admin not a dev, (but reading my ass off). I can get the scrtipt to work downloading attachments from inbox in outlook but need it to download attachments from a subfolder instead:

```
############################# Outlook Call ##############################

$olFolderInbox = 6 
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$messages = $inbox.items 
write-host $messages.count 
$messcount = $messages.count 




foreach($message in $messages){ 


##############Save Attachments################

$filepath = "c:\attachments\" 
$message.attachments|foreach { 
    Write-Host $_.filename 
    $attr = $_.filename 

    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $_.filename))

    $a = $_.filename 
    If ($a.Contains("")) { 
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a)) 
                             } 
  } 

}



###########END##########
```

Any Ideas anyone? Would be massively grateful.

Answer (score 1):

```
$OutputFolder = 'C:\tests';
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application; 
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'colour' `
    | % Items `
    | % Attachments `
    | % {
        $OutputFileName = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.FileName;
        if (Test-Path $OutputFileName) {
            $FileDirectoryName = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutputFileName);
            $FileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($OutputFileName);
            $FileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($OutputFileName);

            for ($i = 2; Test-Path $OutputFileName; $i++) {
                $OutputFileName = "{0} ({1}){2}" -f (Join-Path -Path $FileDirectoryName -ChildPath $FileNameWithoutExtension), $i, $FileExtension;
            }
        }
        Write-Host $OutputFileName;
        $_.SaveAsFile($OutputFileName)
    }

Remove-Item -Path C:\tests\*.jpg
Remove-Item -Path C:\tests\*.png

Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.docx” –Verb Print -PassThru  
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.xlsx” –Verb Print -PassThru  
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.doc” –Verb Print -PassThru  
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.xls” –Verb Print -PassThru  
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.pptx” –Verb Print -PassThru 
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.ppt” –Verb Print -PassThru
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.xls” –Verb Print -PassThru 
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.msg” –Verb Print -PassThru 
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.xlsm” –Verb Print -PassThru 
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.rtf” –Verb Print -PassThru 
Start-Process –FilePath “c:\tests\*.pdf” –Verb Print -PassThru `
%{sleep 3;$_}
Remove-Item -Path C:\tests\*.*
```

This accomplishes what i need, i might put a kill process in after each one just to make sure there is no doc stuck.

But - The 1 thing left to accomplish is i need this to write to a non default printer and not change the existing default? This runs on a server with a vbscript already running utilizing default printer so it will mess that up if it changes.

Comment: (taken out the -passthru parameter as it was unnecessary)

Answer (score 0):

As usual with COM Objects, it's pretty ugly to do.

You're supposed to do it like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624135/accessing-folders-in-outlook-with-vba), but I can't get that to work at all.  `$Inbox.Folders['FolderName']` returns nothing, and `$Inbox.Folders('FolderName')` returns an error.

Here's how I can get it to work.  I'm on PowerShell v4 with Office 2013.

Say you've got a folder at \\Inbox\eReports\Amazon\StatsReports, and you want all the messages in it.

```
$Messages = $inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'eReports' `
    | % Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'Amazon' `
    | % Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'StatsReports' `
    | % Items;
```

Note that the way I'm using `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` require PowerShell v3.  Under earlier versions this would be *considerably* more verbose.

---

Here's a full version of the script that works for me on Win 7 x64/PowerShell v4/Office 2013.  I've tested it on a few different folders, so it should work.

It will automatically rename files with duplicate names, following the Windows convention of adding a `(2)`, then a `(3)` and so on.

```
$OutputFolder = 'C:\OutputFolder';

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application; 
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'eReports' `
    | % Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'Amazon' `
    | % Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'StatsReports' `
    | % Items `
    | % Attachments `
    | % {
        $OutputFileName = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.FileName;
        if (Test-Path $OutputFileName) {
            $FileDirectoryName = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutputFileName);
            $FileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($OutputFileName);
            $FileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($OutputFileName);

            for ($i = 2; Test-Path $OutputFileName; $i++) {
                $OutputFileName = "{0} ({1}){2}" -f (Join-Path -Path $FileDirectoryName -ChildPath $FileNameWithoutExtension), $i, $FileExtension;
            }
        }
        Write-Host $OutputFileName;
        $_.SaveAsFile($OutputFileName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ive got PSVersion 5.0 and Office 2010. When i add this code in though and replace the variable $messages and folder name with my subfolder i am not getting the result, where would i place your code in the existing script above? Sorry for the lame Q

Comment: Hi, ive managed to get that running, only needed 1 folder so section:$inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'colour' `
    | % Items `
    | % Attachments `
    | % {

Comment: Is correct above, last puzzle for me is, how would i auto print each attachment as it is saved to the output folder?

Comment: @Royston Printing is possible, but not straightforward.  For plain text, you can pipe the files to `Out-Printer`.  For some docs like Word or PDF, you should be able to use `Start-Process -Path <DocumentFileName> -Verb Print`, but that may or may not work perfectly and you might need to [play around](https://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/) if it leaves the document open.  I'm not sure how you'd print documents that don't have a Print verb, however.